# Google Cloud Storage propagation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How long does it take for a change to a file in Google Cloud Storage to propagate?

I'm having this very frustrating problem where I change the contents of a file and re-upload it via gsutil, but the change doesn't show up for several hours.  Is there a way to force a changed file to propagate everything immediately?

If I look at the file in the Google Cloud Storage console, it sees the new file, but then if I hit the public URL it's an old version and in some cases, 2 versions ago.

Is there a header that I'm not setting?

EDIT:

I tried `gsutil -h "Cache-Control: no-cache" cp -a public-read MyFile` and it doesn't help, but maybe the old file needs to expire before the new no-cache version takes over?

I did a curl -I on the file and get this back:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Dec 12 2012 15:53:08 (1355356388)
Expires: Fri, 21 Dec 2012 19:58:39 GMT
Date: Fri, 21 Dec 2012 18:58:39 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 21 Dec 2012 18:53:41 GMT
ETag: "66d820174d6de17a278b327e4c3e9b4e"
x-goog-sequence-number: 3
x-goog-generation: 1356116021512000
x-goog-metageneration: 1
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Language: en
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 160
Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600, no-transform
Age: 3449
```

Which seems to indicate it will expire in an hour, despite the no-cache.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage provides strong data consistency: once a write completes, a read from anywhere in the world will get the most recent data.

However, if you enable caching (which by default is true for any publicly readable object), reads of that object can see a version of the object as old as the Cache-Control max-age specified on the object. If, for example, you uploaded the file like this:

```
gsutil cp -a public-read file gs://my_bucket/file
```

You can see that the max-age is 1 hour (3600 seconds):

```
gsutil ls -L gs://my_bucket/file
gs://my_bucket/file:
    Creation time:  Fri, 21 Dec 2012 19:59:57 GMT
    Cache-Control:  public, max-age=3600, no-transform
    Content-Length: 1065
    Content-Type:   text/plain
    ETag:       eb3fb83beedf1efffe5b8e32e8d6a65a
    ...
```

If you want to prevent a publicly readable object from being cached you could do:

```
gsutil setmeta -h Cache-Control:no-cache gs://my_bucket/file
```

Alternatively, you could set a shorter max-age on the object:

```
gsutil setmeta -h 'Cache-Control:public, max-age=600, no-transform'
```

Mike Schwartz, Google Cloud Storage team

Comment: I updated my questions to include that I tried no-cache, but I'm still seeing the max-age=3600. Does the old file need to expire before the new no-cache file takes over?

Comment: OK, it does seem to be the case that you have to wait for the old cached version to expire before the no-cache version takes over.  Now that it has expired, the no-cache version is showing up correctly.

Comment: @mike it would be nice to have a feature to invalidate/flush the cache like on CDN.

Comment: BigQuery's export to CSV won't let any header be set. Every export

Comment: @mihai - it would be difficult to provide a cache invalidation feature because once served with a non-0 cache TTL any cache on the Internet (not just those under Google's control) is allowed (per HTTP spec) to cache the data.

Comment: hi @MikeSchwartz thank you for the answer but I still have issue: as described here[1] if I upload a non-public file and then share publicity the file hasn't the cache-control meta. I still getting propagation issue: if I add a random ?adfjhdfbsdjh as url query string I see the last version of the file. Without the query string I see the old version. Any idea?


[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#cache-control

Comment: @aqquadro: Please email the bucket and object name with which you're seeing this problem to gs-team@google.com (and mention my name), and I'll take a look.

Comment: After discussing with @aqquadro I figured out the issue: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#cache-control incorrectly stated that uploading a non-public object and then setting the ACL to public-read would result in a non-cacheable object. In fact the HTTP spec allows public objects to be cached by default, so to inhibit caching you need to set a Cache-Control header, for example using the command: gsutil -h Cache-Control:private cp -a public-read file.png gs://your-bucket.  (I'll also fix the incorrect documentation.)

Comment: Is it possible to disable cache for a whole bucket?

Comment: @Pier - not in one request. You'd have to do something like:

gsutil -m -h "Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" gs://your-bucket/** 

which will make a request for every object in the bucket.

Comment: What about non public files? are they cached by default?

Comment: Just in case anybody is doing copy-pasta, the command Mike gave to add the no cache headers should be `gsutil -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" gs://your-bucket/**` - basically missing the `setmeta`.

Comment: Not for me, it doesn't. I clear cache in my browser and the old file is still there. It will be changed in a few hours, but this is really annoying as I have to change urls on my website to test design.