# PHP Google App Engine permanently delete Image from Cloud Storage

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm using GAE version 1.9.0 and I want to delete an image from the data storage and upload another image to its location. This is how I'm doing it right now.

```
unlink("gs://my_storage/images/test.jpg");
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],'gs://my_storage/images/test.jpg');
```

And then I want to get the Image serving URL of the latest uploaded image, and I do it like this.

```
$image_link = CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl("gs://my_storage/images/test.jpg");
```

The issue is, when the name of the deleted image("test.jpg") and the uploaded image("test.jpg") is the same, **the old file is served** when I call for the newly uploaded file(I think it is cached.)

Is there anyway I can permanently delete this file without caching it?

Comment: I think this is a caching problem. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996116/google-cloud-storage-propagation

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter, but if the cache is disabled, that would be a problem right? Like it would take alot of time to load the image. Is there a way to delete the image and the cache, so the cache will be served untill the image is deleted?

Comment: Did you clear your own browser cache?

Comment: Yes. That was the first thing I did.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably delete the original serving URL before creating another with the same name.

There's a deleteImageServingUrl() method in CloudStorageTools that you can use to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is how to do in php laravel.

```
 $object = $post_media->media_cloud;
 $objectname = substr($object,48,100); 
 $bucket = Storage::disk('gcs')->delete($objectname);
```

1. Here in $object i get google cloud image url from db
2. Then we take only object name from that url, by substr.
3. Since you have given in your config Storage class as **Storage::disk('gcs')**

so this will call the function **delete** by taking the **objectname**.

Hope it helps anyone.

Note : For multiple images either pass an array of objects, or repeat it foreach loop.