# Set default settings to 'no-cache' on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

Is there a way to set all public links to have 'no-cache' in Google Cloud Storage?

I've seen solutions to [use gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#cache-control) to set the "Cache-Control" upon file-upload, but I'm looking for a more permanent solution.

There was [a conversation about providing a cache invalidation feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996116/google-cloud-storage-propagation) but I didn't quite follow the reasoning. Any explanations would be greatly appreciated!

> it would be difficult to provide a cache invalidation feature because once served with a non-0 cache TTL any cache on the Internet (not just those under Google's control) is allowed (per HTTP spec) to cache the data

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'more permanent'?

Comment: I was hoping to set "no-cache" Account wide once and then forget about it. Currently, I need to set the "Cache-Control" to "no-cache" every time I re-upload a file.

Comment: The default behavior is no caching.

Comment: For private objects, the default is no caching. For public objects, the default is "public, max-time=3600". There is not currently a way to change the default behavior.

Comment: What API are you using to upload objects?

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough darn. thanks!

Comment: @jterrace I'm using the console UI to upload the objects.

Comment: In the UI, you can select the object and click on "Edit metadata" to edit the cache control. I don't think there's a way to set a default or set it on upload.

Comment: You should file a Feature Request to add this https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request

Comment: Regarding your question about providing a cache invalidation feature: The problem is that once an object has been served with caching enabled, it can be cached anywhere on the Internet -- not just at Google-managed sites. There's no way to know all the sites where an object has been cached (imagine a cache running inside a corporate network behind a firewall), hence no way to invalidate all copies.

Answer (score 0):

For a more permanent one-time-effort solution, with the *current* offerings on GCP, you can do this with **Cloud Functions**.

Create a new Funciton, set the **Event type** to "On (finalizing/creating) file in the selected bucket" - `google.storage.object.finalize`. Make sure to select the bucket you want this on. In the body of the function, set the `cacheControl` / [`Cache-Control`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#cache-control) attribute for the blob. The attribute name depends on the language. Here's my version in Python, using [`cache_control`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#storage-view-object-metadata-python):

`main.py`:
match the function name below to the `Entry point`

```py
from google.cloud import storage

def set_file_uncached(event, context):
    file = event  # auto-generated
    print(f"Processing file: {file=}")  # logging, if you want it
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    # we expect just one with that name
    blob = storage_client.bucket(file["bucket"]).get_blob(file["name"])
    if not blob:
        # in case the blob is deleted before this executes
        print(f"blob not found")
        return None
    blob.cache_control = "public, max-age=0"  # or whatever you need
    blob.patch()
```

`requirements.txt`

```
google-cloud-storage
```

From the logs: `Function execution took 1712 ms, finished with status: 'ok'`. This could have been faster but I've set the minimum to `0` instances so it needs to spin-up for each upload. Depending on your usage and cost constraints, you can set it to `1` or something higher.

Other settings:

Retry on failure: No/False
Region: [wherever your bucket is]
Memory allocated: 128 MB (smallest available currently)
Timeout: 5 seconds (smallest available currently, function shouldn't take longer)
Minimum instances: 0
Maximum instances: 1